# Using and adapting bbc style theme in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend, axis-labels

I am trying to use the bbc style theme to make my plots in gg plots nicer. However, I am finding that bbc style theme automatically removes axis labels and legend labels, even if I include axis labels and legend labels in my code.

Here is information about the theme:

```
https://bbc.github.io/rcookbook/ 
https://github.com/bbc/bbplot/blob/master/README.md
https://github.com/bbc/bbplot/blob/master/R/bbc_style.R
```

I have read that I would need to edit the theme manually:

"bbc_style (): has no arguments and is added to the gg plot chain after you have created a plot. What it does is generally makes text size, font and colour, axis lines, axis text and many other standard chart components into BBC style, which has been formulated together with the Visual Journalism design team.

The function is pretty basic and does not change or adapt based on the type of chart you are making, so in some cases you will need to make additional theme arguments in your gg plot chain if you want to make any additions or changes to the style, for example, to add or remove gridlines etc."

My code is:

```
  Cars_region_plots <- Cars_region %>%
  ggplot(Cars_region, mapping = aes(x= cars_none, y= region)) +
  geom_point(col ="tomato2", size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3) +
  labs(title = "How does household car ownership vary?", subtitle = "Proportion of car-less households in England",
       x = "Proportion of car-less households", y = "region") +
  bbc_style() +
```

Would appreciate it if anyone can help me out by letting me know how to add theme () so that the axis labels (and also legend, for a different example) show up. Or even to point me to some resources, as I haven't had much luck online.

Comment: The code is not reproducible. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Cars_region)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Cars_region, 20))`.

Comment: I would suggest this resource about creating a new theme: https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/building-a-new-theme.html. Hope it helps